# What is a Naga Bandham?

Tags: belief, mantras

In Hindu Tantric traditions, what causes someone to use a *Naga Bandham* (snake binding spell) to protect sacred doors?

Recently it was in popular culture because the final door at [Padmanabhaswamy Temple is alleged to be closed with a naga-bandham](http://www.amazingbharat.com/2014/02/mystery-behind-seventh-door-of-shri.html).

What is this snake spell? What does it protect? How does it work?

Comment: secret of naga bandham of padmaswamy temple

Answer (score 3):

its a lock unlocked by the sound waves of a particular person's voice when he says a particular word (spell). the lock consists of many mechanical links. the sound waves gets amplified and forced on a small mechanical link. the movement gets converted into some other movements of different parts and the door unlocks

if another person tries to open with same spell or different spell, the sound waves generated are directed to other side which causes danger like communicating with nearest snakes and make them attack

Comment: dude its what i think am not sure

Comment: You should cite sources.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by user7381 is not convincing. Actually it is bogus! My be the answer is in this Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-oMSCzv5kw&ab_channel=PraveenMohanHindi
It in Hindilanguage.